# C++: Making a function friend of multiple classes?

Tags: c++, oop, friend, friend-function

Here's a Doubly Linked List class that I wrote:

```
template <class T>
class DLL
{
    class Node
    {
        T m_data;
        Node* m_prev;
        Node* m_next;

        Node(const T& data) :m_data{ data }, m_prev{ nullptr }, m_next{ nullptr }{}

        friend class DLL;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& node)
        {
            out << node.m_data;
            return out;
        }
    };

    Node* m_first = nullptr;

public:
    DLL& add(const T& data)
    {
        Node* temp = new Node{ data };

        if (m_first)
        {
            temp->m_next = m_first;
            m_first->m_prev = temp;
            m_first = temp;
        }
        else {
            m_first = temp;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const DLL& dll)
    {
        Node* trav = dll.m_first;
        while (trav)
        {
            out << *trav << ' ';
            trav = trav->m_next; //C2248: Cannot access private member declared in class DLL::Node.
        }
        return out;
    }

    ~DLL()
    {
        Node* trav = m_first->m_next;
        Node* foll = m_first;

        while (trav)
        {
            delete foll;
            foll = trav;
            trav = trav->m_next;
        }
        delete foll;
    }
};
```

In the `DLL`'s friend function to output the `DLL` into stream, there's an error that pops up saying the function cannot access a private member of the class `Node`.

After a couple of tries, I came up with a solution by declaring this friend function as a friend of the `Node` class as seen below:

```
class Node
    {
        T m_data;
        Node* m_prev;
        Node* m_next;

        Node(const T& data) :m_data{ data }, m_prev{ nullptr }, m_next{ nullptr }{}

        friend class DLL;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& node)
        {
            out << node.m_data;
            return out;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const DLL& dll);
    };
```

Now the function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const DLL& dll)` is able to access `m_next` in the `Node` class and everything's working fine...or so I think.

My question here is: **Can a function be a friend of more than one class as we see here or does what I've done invoke undefined behavior?**

Comment: Note: DLL usually means "dynamic link library", not "doubly-linked list".

Comment: @Nelfeal I know. I was doing this because I just felt like making a doubly linked list. I wasn't gonna implement this in any production code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a function can be a friend of more than one class.

But friends are not inherited, so even if `operator<<` is a friend of `DLL<T>` and `DLL<T>` a friend of `DLL<T>::Node`, it doesn't automatically make `operator<<` a friend of `DLL<T>::Node`, hence it can't access the `private DLL<T>::Node::m_next`.

The solution is to declare it a friend of `DLL<T>::Node`, like you did.

Answer (score 1):

A friend function declaration in some class only *designates* the function as a friend of that class, not as a member. You can absolutely make a function friend of multiple classes. For example:

```
class B;

class A {
    int a = 2;
    friend auto operator+(A a, B b) -> int;
};

class B {
    int b = 5;
    friend auto operator+(A a, B b) -> int;
};

auto operator+(A a, B b) -> int {
    return a.a + b.b;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c89eea543c11af7b)